# difference between youtube's request and mine

Tags: javascript, post, youtube

i want to make a script that makes every video's comment section look like the ones that still have the old kind.
for example, videos on this channel:https://www.youtube.com/user/TheMysteryofGF/videos
in Firebug, in the Net tab, i noticed the comment JSON file's URL it is requested from is different.
i tried to run a code on the youtube watch page which would request the file the same way, but it doesnt work, and in firebug it says it was forbidden.
the URL is the same, they are both POST, and i cant figure out what is different. i can even resend the original request in firebug and it works... so anyway, here is a code i tried on a video with "1vptNpkysBQ" video url.

```
var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
  var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'
    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
    : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  xhr.open('post', url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var status;
    var data;
     // https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // `DONE`
      status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        successHandler && successHandler(data);
       } else {
        errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};

getJSON('https://www.youtube.com/watch_fragments_ajax?v=1vptNpkysBQ&tr=time&frags=comments&spf=load', function(data) {
  alert('Your public IP address is: ' + data);
}, function(status) {
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ajax to get data.  Ajax has 1 restriction: You can only get data from your own server.  When you try to get data from another server/domain, you get a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

Any time you put http:// (or https://) in the url, you get this error.

You'll have to do it the Youtube way.

---

That's why they made the javascript API.  Here is (the principal of) how it works. You can link javascript files from other servers, with the < script > tag

So if you could find a javascript file that starts with

```
var my_videos = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world'];
```

then you can use var my_videos anywhere in your script.  This can be used both for functions and for data.  So the server puts this (dynamically generated) script somewhere, on a specific url.  You, the client website can use it.

If you want to really understand it, you should try building your own API; you'll learn a lot.

---

Secondary thing: Use GET.

POST means the client adds data to the server (example: post a comment, upload a file, ...).  GET means you send some kind of ID to the server, then the server returns its own data to the client.

So what you are doing here, is pure GET.

Comment: but i run the script on the youtube domain, so even if its not my own server, shouldnt it work the same way the original youtube script does?
https://d.maxfile.ro/rnimomrrag.PNG you can see in this image that the first one, which is my request is forbidden, and the fourth one, which is done by youtube is not. they also use POST, and if i run the same script on the page a similar way, it should work the same way, right?

Comment: No you don't.  Only if you work inside Google do you work on the youtube domain.  You may not have http:// in the url of an Ajax request.

Comment: but if i run a javascript code on the page its the same as youtube's own script running if im right. so i should be able to do the same thing the original script does.. could you see the request in firebug or an other way? i would basically just need to reproduce the request. the URL should be right, since it clearly leads to the file when opened in firebug (right click on the request, open in new tab) but just going to the URL itself doesnt lead to the file..